# How do I install moment-timezone.js on Bluemix?

Tags: javascript, ibm-cloud, momentjs, package.json, node-red

Ultra green on this stuff!

I am working with Node Red on Bluemix within the Bluemix Web IDE and also some custom javascript within Node Red. I am trying to get the right date and time through daylight savings and was referred to use Moment-Timezone.js (http://momentjs.com/timezone/) as a reliable way to do so.

I can't figure out how to get this installed on Bluemix or frankly any library generally. Much clearer to do so locally. I have been trying to stay on the web IDE in the short term until I understand things better.

All the info I found indicated that I have to somehow add this to my package.json file and that will cause the package? to install and be available so that I can call the functions in my custom javascript.

If this is right, I do not know the right format and parameters to use within the .json file. Searched but couldn't find help on that either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to add packages to the package.json and then redeploy the application. As part of deploying Bluemix will read the package.json and download those along with your application.

Details of the package.json format can be found [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json)

But basically it wants to go in the [dependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies) section.

e.g.

```
...
dependencies: {
  "foo": "1.0.0",
  "bar": "1.5.x" 
},
...
```